# Is it permitted to shave during Sefirah for an engagement party?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, shaving, engagement-shidduch

The Mishnah Berurah (Orach Chayim 493:3) says that one may make an engagement party during sefirah. Is one permitted to shave in order to look presentable for the party?

Comment: Whose party? If you are the choson or the father (of either) you can keep the other part of sefirah. If you are a guest, you do not have to shave.

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887)! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I suggest that you [edit your profile](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name!

Comment: @sabba what if it's the part that everyone keeps and what if the guest is a close relative? Your solution doesn't really deal with all the cases

Answer (score 2):

Both the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (120) and the Aruch Hashulchan (493) allow the Mohel and the father of the baby to shave and have a haircut the afternoon before the Bris.

Neither of them mentions this regarding engagement parties, even though they both stress they are permitted, albeit without dancing and music.

This leads me to conclude that shaving and haircuts are forbidden for engagement parties during the Sefira, for all participants.

(I don't have a Mishna Berura handy, but IIRC he follows the same pattern.)

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [סימן קכ - הלכות ספירת העמר וימי הספירה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0119_L2)

> **סעיף ח'** 
>   הַסַּנְדָּק (הוּא הַתּוֹפֵס אֶת הַתִּינוֹק בִּשְׁעַת מִילָה) וְהַמּוֹהֵל, וַאֲבִי הַבֵּן, מֻתָּרִין לְהִסְתַּפֵּר בְּיּוֹם שֶׁלִּפְנֵי הַמִּילָה סָמוּךְ לָעֶרֶב קֹדֶם הֲלִיכָה לְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת. ‏
>
> **סעיף ט'** 
>   לַעֲשׂוֹת שִׁדּוּכִין אֲפִלּוּ בַּסְּעוּדָּה, מֻתָּרִין בְּכָל הַיָּמִים. אַךְ רִקּוּדִין וּמְחוֹלוֹת, אֲסוּרִין. ‏

Aruch Hashulchan [סימן תצג - דינים הנוהגים בימי העומר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0402_L2)

> **ב** ... אבל לארס ולקדש – שפיר דמי. וכן אצלנו לעשות **שידוכים** ולכתוב תנאים – מותר, שמא יקדמנו אחר. **ומותר לעשות סעודה**, אך לא בריקודין ומחולות. וכל שכן שאסור לזמר בכלי זמר. וכן סעודת הרשות מותר, כמו סעודות מריעות, ובלבד בלא ריקודין ומחולות. ‏
>
> **ג** וכן נהגו במדינות אלו **שלא להסתפ**ר בימים אלו, והוא גם כן עניין אבלות. ומי שהסתפר – קונסין אותו על שעבר על המנהג ולא עשה מצוה. ופשוט הוא דאם צריך לבריאותו להסתפר דמותר. וכן כשיש **מילה** בימים אלו מותרים בעלי הברית, דהיינו המוהל והסנדק ואבי הבן, להסתפר ביום שלפני המילה סמוך לערב, מפני שיום טוב שלהם הוא. ‏